# excel batch pasting formulas

Tags: excel

I have a list of documents that I want to paste relative links to in Excel. I converted the list to a list of Excel formulas that look like

```
=HYPERLINK(".\docs\123abc\1.doc","1.doc")
=HYPERLINK(".\docs\456abc\1.doc","1.doc")
```

However when I paste this in Excel it will paste the text for the formula and not actually make it a formula. I have tried creating a macro to set each cell's FormulaR1C1 value as the value from the text in the cell and that didn't fix it. As well I have tried to copy and paste special as forumla and that did nothing either.

If I type in each formula by hand instead of copying and pasting them it works great, however the list of forumlas I have is a couple hundred and I would prefer not to have to type each one in by hand. Does anyone have any experience with this or suggestions on getting the forumla to register?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before pasting the formulas,

1. Select all cells in worksheet
2. Right click and select "Format Cells..."
3. In the Number tab page, select General and click OK button.
4. Paste your formulas list.