# Pasting formulas across workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

So I have about 50 columns worth of formulas to paste over onto new workbooks on a regular basis. Pasting them one by one works, meaning all references are identically positioned when I paste them across.

However, if I try to paste more than 1 column formula at a time, I get:

> The range you are pasting from contains formulas that cannot be pasted into this instance of Excel.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662741/excel-batch-pasting-formulas) and a couple other links, any idea if this can be done without VBA?
If not, any idea how to write this in VBA? tyvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you simply copy the workbook and paste the new data in the place of the old data? Not the most technical answer, but it should do the trick?

Comment: doesn't help me understand why I cant paste formulas over, but I really like your style! no reason why this wouldn't work, so i'll wait for an explanation and eventually accept your answer

Comment: Sweet, hope the exceling goes well.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it suited your needs.